# Odd rectangle under reputation in meta profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, site-design

There is an odd grey rectangle under the reputation on [meta profile page](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/users/32091/qwertiy?tab=badges). And it almost overlaps with label about top percentage just bellow it:

[image: screenshot from meta]

If I open profile page on the main site, I see nothing like that:

[image: screenshot from main site]

I think, that background on meta (caused by `bg-black-050` class) have to be removed.

Comment: This occurs on other sites (both beta and graduated) too. This might get more attention on [Mother meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @James It was posted already in the Meta Stack Exchange [Padding / bg-color issue in all the per site meta - activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316475/312043)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The different background color on the meta profile rep has been removed, resolving this issue.